# Xamarin - break on handled exceptions

Tags: xamarin

I'm using Xamarin on my Mac, and I want to break on all exceptions. For that, I go to Run / Exceptions, and I select everything.

But now, Xamarin breaks in assembly code, which I don't want. I have checked in general preferences / debugger, the "debug project code only" is checked.

How do I tell Xamarin to only break on user code ?

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.0.1 on Mac OS 10.9.3

Thank you!

## Edit

To be clear, if I select all exceptions (or just System.Exception, it makes no difference) in run / exceptions, and then I try to debug a unit test that I know throws a handled exception somewhere, I get this:

[image: step into assembly code]

If I click "continue execution", I get a thousand more exceptions. I don't care about Mono exceptions, I only want exceptions thrown from the code I write and the libraries I use.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no need to select everything, just select System.Exception.
2. It's not possible to stop on only exceptions that occur in user code. The setting "Debug project code only" defines whether the debugger will step into or step over calls into framework code.

Comment: 1. Yes but it's much more simple to cmd+A. The same occurs with only System.Exception anyway. 2. I'm sorry what? You mean that I HAVE to debug Mono code? The one that throws exceptions around like it's the end of the world? Maybe I wasn't very clear with the question, I'll clarify it.

Comment: Why not just select a more specific exception type than System.Exception (or the entire list)?

Comment: Because I don't know what type of exception might be thrown, for instance? It's not my library I'm testing, and for all I know, there might be exceptions catched that should not be.

Comment: Then try to do this: Select all exception types, before you remove those you're not interested in (for your screenshot, that would be System.Net.Sockets.SocketException and all its superclasses (Win32Exception : ExternalException : SystemException : Exception as can be seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx)